# Sharepoint 2010 Application Page timeout issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010, applicationpage

I am using SharePoint Application page for effective search.Here i am using few textbox to get input from user.Based on the input i wrote object model code to fetch data from SharePoint list.Its working fine when search item below 500 items(few Seconds).But the page is not responding for long running process.

Answer (score 0):

For long duration operations you may use SPLongOperation class to help you.

See: http://sharepointzen.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/using-splongoperation-for-synchronous-long-running-tasks-in-sharepoint/